# htaccess 500 internal server error in wordpress or 404 on page changes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am now trying to resolve the issue, which appeared after i have linked my website, parked on a server (in the manner **www.serwer123456.host.pl/main**) to a domain bought on the very same server.

Basically, after contacting the support I am certain that the problem lies within htaccess file in my wordpress installation. The website works just fine when I use **serwer123456** address, but when I try to access it through the **mydomain.pl** it gives a 500 error.

I've tried changing the htaccess a couple of times but it only led me to the point, when the **mydomain.pl** works, but when I try to access anything else on the site (**mydomain.pl/category**) it throws a 404 page not found.

Again I've been assured by the hosting company that everything works on their end and that there is *SOMETHING* wrong with my htaccess file. I would be extremely thankful for any guidance as to how to resolve this issue.

My htaccess is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /main/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This is the state when it displays the **mydomain.pl** site and gives 404 errors on any **/category**

Comment: First things first, remove the `.htaccess` or temporary rename it to `backup.ht` then try to access your domain and see if it works, once you confirm the domain works as expect then we can start messing with the `.htaccess`.

Comment: I've tried doing that, when the htaccess is renamed, the same thing happens, main site works fine, rest gives 404 errors

Comment: Does your host have cPanel? And if possible tell me the hosting company site.

Comment: It has a cPanel, but everything that I can do there is simply configuring the domain redirect (which I've been assured is correct)
The hosting company is home.pl

Comment: Well the correct for what you want would be creating your domain.pl as an addon domain into a folder of your choice. Which is possible with cPanel if they allow you to have more than 1 addon domain. This way it would be accessible by the domain as long as that domain DNS is pointed to your hosting company.

Comment: Error code 500 stands for internal server error. .htaccess is nothing but a directory level Apache configuration file. If the problem persists, even after removing the .htaccess file, then I'd start looking from problems elsewhere.

Could you post the link of your site, so that I can have a look at it?